# Capturing exit code of n child processes

Tags: c, unix

I am trying to **fork()** `10` child processes in one loop and then in another loop **wait()** for them to terminate and print their **PID** along with their **exit status code**. It cannot be done any other way or using any other function. Two loops/waves and the function wait();
This is what I have tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    pid_t wait_p, p[10], p_child;
    int status;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        p[i] = fork();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        switch (p[i])
        {
        case 0:
            p_child = getpid();
            exit(p_child % 10);
            break;
        case -1:
            puts("ERROR");
            break;
        default:
            wait_p = wait(&status);
            printf("Child with PID: %d", wait_p);
            if (WIFEXITED(status))
                printf(" terminated with STATUS: %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
            break;
        }
    }

    return (EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

This code will execute an endless count of child processes. It must print only the first original(issued by **THE** one parent) `10`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your main forks 10 processes before it checks to see it it's a child process. Move the 10 forks into the switch in the case 0 logic.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have to fork them in one loop and then wait for them to finish in another.

Comment: You create 1024 processes in the first loop — two to the power of ten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to handle the child processes directly in your first loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    p[i] = fork();
    if (p[i] == 0) {
        p_child = getpid();
        exit(p_child % 10);
    } else if (p[i] == -1) {
            perror("fork");
    }        
}
```

and then wait for them in the second loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{       
        wait_p = wait(&status);
        printf("Child with PID: %d", wait_p);
        if (WIFEXITED(status))
                printf(" terminated with STATUS: %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
}
```

You cannot handle the case, that `fork()` returns in the child process (yielding 0 as return value), in your second loop, otherwise each child process in the first loop keeps forking more child processes.